# How to get the status of a serial COM port

Tags: windows, delphi, serial-port

What I mean is that, when I code a project, I need to communicate with the serial port like *COM1*, *COM2*... but sometimes there is no device connected and I also can use the function `CreateFile` to get the *COM* port handle.

When I use the `WriteFile` function to send a string to the *COM* port the software blocks.

After I dig into the problem I find another function `GetCommModemStatus` which can get status of the *COM* port but when I use the **usb-rs232** transition line, the second parameter always returns `0`.

How can I get the *COM* port status so that I can check if is there some devices connected to the computer?

Comment: All com devices do not set the status signals. The only safe way to detect a device is to try to communicate with it. With a proper timeout on the communication, you can detect the presence of a device. This way of detection presumes you know what type of device you are communicating with.

Comment: You cannot open non-existent serial port, for a starters.

Comment: Suggest not using the ancient `CreateFile` and `WriteFile` methods for RS-232.  There are several very well written serial communication libraries that will serve you far better (I can recommend AsyncPro).  As for the "COM port status" are you asking how to enumerate the *installed* COM ports on the system, or are you asking how to detect if a device is physically connected to a COM port that you already know exists on the system?

Comment: I'm asking how to detect if a device is physically connected to a COM port that you already know exists on the system.Do you know how to get it?

Comment: @J... How do the libraries implement any of this? On top of CreateFile, WriteFile etc. The fact that these functions are ancient does not make them not current.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The decription is hyperbolic, I apologize.  The real problem is that they are such low level ingredients in the solution that they are unlikely to produce a robust solution for OP.  Being I/O, it quickly becomes unwise to perform RS-232 operations in the main thread.  Writing multithreaded I/O is difficult.  A good library already does this.  One needs a good reason to reinvent the wheel, I should think, rather than needing a reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to detect if a device is connected to your COM port and ready to accept packets. If that's the case, you need to check control signals (DTR/DSR and CTS/RTS) before sending data, assuming your device is aware of them and sets the appropriate PIN on your DB-9 or DB-25 connector. Some devices rely on software handshaking instead (XON/XOFF) and do not set control signals. Your best bet would be to consult documentation of your device.

I have been using ComPort Library version 4.10 by Dejan Crnila. It does support both hardware and software handshakings, so you can focus on your own code instead of *reinventing the wheel*.

Comment: Plenty of devices use neither control signals nor any sort of handshaking.  For those, the only way to tell if they're there is to send them a query and see if there is a response.  Even then, that's only effective if you have the port configured correctly (baud rate, stop bits, etc).

Comment: @J... Of course the approach should be device (or at least protocol) specific. I have had to deal with various medical equipment which communicate using RS-232, and was able to categorize them into different protocols. Some used hardware handshaking, while others used software or no handshaking at all.

Answer (score 1):

As several people have already pointed out, it is not a good idea to try to "re-invent the wheel." Except for "quick and dirty" testing, your code will have to handle the com port in a separate thread and the available solutions all make this much easier.

BUT, if you Really want to do it, I'll give you some pointers.

If you are using "WriteFile" then you have probably already figured out the "CreateFile" part of the procedure and how complicated things can get depends upon what kind of IO you specified in that procedure, Overlapped or not. Overlapped IO is more complicated but does let the OS handle some of the burden.

You mentioned that your call to "WriteFile" hangs. You should look up the "SetCommTimeOuts" function. Setting both the WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier and WriteTotalTimeoutConstant members of TCommTimeouts to zero will tell the OS to return immediately. You may also need to "SetCommMask" if your target uses handshaking.

What happens next really depends on what your target is supposed to do. The GetCommMask function can be used to check the status of the handshake lines.